# Ubuntu live freezes (MacBook Pro)

Tags: macbook, live-cd, macbook-pro

When I run ubuntu live, if it works correctly for a few minutes, but then it freezes, and checking the log, I found this error, I'm running on a **MacBook Pro (13-inch)**

- 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5
- memory 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB

This I found in the log, what will be the error.

[image: log Photo]